# How to handle errors from within a callback in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, promise, callback

I have this code that invokes a function and has a callback with error and data parameters:

```
app.get('/lights', (req,res) => {
    hue.getLights(function(err, data){
        if(err) res.status(401).send("An error occured: ", err.message);
        res.send(data);
    });
})
```

The function that it invokes is:

```
let getLights = function(callback){
    fetch(`http://${gateway}/api/${username}/lights`, {
        method: 'GET'
    }).then((res) => {
        if(res.ok){
            return res.json();
        }else{
            throw new Error(res.message);
        }
    }).then((json) => {
        lightsArray = []
        for (var i in json){
            lightsArray.push(`ID: ${i} Name: ${json[i]['name']}`);
        }
        return callback(lightsArray);
    });
}
```

When I make an error occur, the error isn't caught, nor is any error displayed, the app crashes with the message: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().`

Now I know I'm missing a lot, this is my first time using callbacks, let alone handling errors.

Could someone help me with making the error callback work, also show me some flaws in what I'm doing, as I know this won't catch every error that may happen, only errors caused by using the fetch function.

Thanks!

This is my other function (similar but uses a catch aswell, which I think I have done incorrectly too):

```
let getLightDetails = function (ID, callback) {
    fetch(`http://${gateway}/api/${username}/lights/${ID}`, {
        method: 'GET'
    }).then((res) => {
        if(res.ok){
            return res.json();
        }else{
            throw new Error(res.message);
        }
    }).then((json) => {
        return callback(json);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return callback(err.message);
    });
}
```

Comment: Add error handling (via `.catch`) to the end of your chain of `.then`s. You don't need to return the promise since you're handling this via a callback anyway. However in that case you should consider converting away from callback-style code entirely or consistently use the node style `callback(err, data)` callbacks.

Comment: you can use .catch to handle the error

Comment: @CRice could you look at my edited post? I added another similar function yet I think I'm using .catch wrongly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing callbacks and promises can make your code a bit messy. I would stick to promises:

```
app.get('/lights', (req, res) => {
  return hue.getLights()
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(401).send("An error occured: ", err.message);
    });
})
```

and **hue.js**

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const gateway = "192.168.0.12";
const username = "username-A";

function fetchAPI(url, ...rest) {
    return fetch(`http://${gateway}/api/${username}${url}`, ...rest);
}

function getLights() {
    return fetchAPI(`/lights`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => json.map((light, i) => `ID: ${i} Name: ${light.name}`));
}

function getLightDetails(id) {
    return fetchAPI(`/lights/${id}`)
    .then(res => res.json());
}

function getLightState(id) {
    return fetchAPI(`/lights/${id}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(light => `Name: ${light.name} On: ${light.state.on}`);
}

function setLightState(id, state) {
    return fetchAPI(`/lights/${id}/state`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({"on": state })
    }).then(res => res.json());
}

module.exports = { getLights, getLightDetails, getLightState, setLightState };
```

Comment: Cheers for your quick answer, I have done that yet I still get an error of  `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to http://192.168.0.12/api/username-A/lights/2/state failed` so I guess I'm not catching the errors the fetch API makes either in that code?

Comment: @Nathan `http://192.168.0.12/api/username-A/lights/2/state` is never called in that function. It should be `/lights`. Are you sure you applied the changes to the correct function? The uncaught error comes from another function

Comment: The `return fetch(`http://${gateway}/api/${username}/lights` line in that function is the `http://192.168.0.12/api/username-A/lights/2/state` I supposed I'm currently checking for errors after the request has been made and completed, and in some cases (like the on I'm In now) the request cannot complete and a new error is thrown before the first time I check for an error?

Comment: I rewrote your entire `hue.js` file using promises. See the edit (oops, I had forgotten to change some `ID`s to `id`, and a pair of parentheses, fixed). And in all your routes, don't forget to do `return hue.XXX().then(...).catch(...)` and not use callbacks

Comment: Thank you! Where would you recommend to learn promises? I've learnt mostly off YouTube so far

Comment: It's hard to choose, there are plenty of resources. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) would probably be the most trusted source, but if you're looking for a shorter read, it looks like [this one](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-promises/) is fine. If you're more of a visual learner, I'm sure you'll find some good videos about them on YouTube. [This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvYYCGs45L4) is really short and well made

Comment: Ill have a look, cheers for the help, really appreactiated